# 自分自身のバッジ数を確認するには？

Tags: サポート, バッジ

どうやって自分のバッジ数を見るのかなど、色々初心者に教えて下さい。
お願いします。
・ω・

Answer (score 9):

ページの最上段に検索窓などのバナーメニューが表示されているかと思いますが、
右上の方に自身のプロフィールページへのリンクが用意されています。

**表示例:**

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

プロフィールページに移動後、画面の中央辺りに概要として獲得済みのバッジ情報が表示されます。
バッジをいくつか獲得後、より詳しい情報を表示したい場合には左側にある「バッジ」のリンクをクリックしてみてください。

**プロフィールページ:**

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

その他、スタックオーバーフローの使い方に関しては、まず [ツアー](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/tour) ページや [ヘルプセンター](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/help) にも情報がまとまっていますので、ぜひ一度目を通してみてください。